# Imagemagik Fred's CYLINDERIZE script is not transforming the image to a gif

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have installed Imagemagik Fred's CYLINDERIZE script by the instructions provided on the website:
http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

I need to transform a png into a cylindric image that is rotating. To do this, I am using the arguments provided by script creator on cylinderize link:
http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/index.php

```
$output = exec(public_path('cyl.sh -m vertical -w 50 -p 25 -a 55 saved.png saved2.gif 2>&1'));
```

The output image is transformed into a cylindric gif but is not rotating. How to make the image rotating?

I have tried also to run the script using linux command line by the instructions but the result is the same.

Comment: I would guess you will need to make multiple images at different angles and compile them into a gif

Comment: A simple script loop was used to process the image multiple time at different rotations. On the cylinderize page in the rotating example it says "Rotation Animation
Arguments:
-m vertical -w 100 -a #
(where # varies from 0 to 360
in 30 degree increments)" So the -a argument was incremented by 30 deg between 0 and 360 to create each frame and then combined into a gif animation.

Comment: @fmw42 What a honor, the creator of the script by himself :)
Ok understood now, thank you both guys for the explanation. 

Based on this, I have a question: What library I should use to transform the images into a gif using PHP/Laravel/jQuery?

Comment: My scripts run via PHP exec(). To create an animation, you will need to create a PHP loop and run the script multiple times at different -a arguments. Then combine them into an animated gif. Please note that if you decide to use any of them for commercial purposes, please contact me for a license.